# docker-compose restart always not issuing run command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am somewhat new to docker-compose and am having trouble with understanding the restart option. I have a container that runs a service talking to Jira, sometimes the container will go down for a variety of reasons. I figured that adding

```
restart: always
```

would cause the container to restart and run the command, however it restarts but never runs the compose command. Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
jira_service:
  container_name: jira_service
  hostname: jira_service
  working_dir: /auto_build
  extends:
    file: ./auto_build/common.yml
    service: auto_build
  command: bash -c "python init_db.py && python jira_service.py"
  links:
    - db
  restart: always
  volumes_from:
    - log_data
```

The documentation for this option is seriously lacking, I am running docker 1.9.1 and docker-compose 1.5.2. Has anyone had success with this?

**EDIT:**

It may be helpful to include the dockerfile that this is being run and built on:

```
FROM python:3.4
ADD . /auto_build
WORKDIR /auto_build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev unixodbc odbc-postgresql
RUN apt-get install -y python-psycopg2
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get install -y git
```

Comment: What command is the container running? The image default?

Comment: Its running python:3.4, would that matter? I added the dockerfile as an edit

Comment: What is the `command` value for your running container (first time started) - `docker ps`. And then after restart.

Comment: the command is simply `bash -c "python init_db.py && python jira_service.py"`, there isn't any other in the dockerfile or common.yml